# Given coordinates, unclear how to convert to GPS

Tags: gps, convert, coordinates

I believe this is "Township and Range" coordinates. 
They were handed to me on paper as: 19T 0345856 over 5000288.

I want to plug into Google Earth or my GPS and find. 
Apparently they are the location in the middle of Maine, USA to a old cavern. The source is an old man, in his 90's and I could not ask technical questions.

Answer (score 1):

The 19T refers to the [UTM Zone](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) for Maine: 19T.

Using a [converter](http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter.aspx) from UTM to Lat/Long:

45°08'21.3"N
70°57'37.9"W

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/45%C2%B008'21.3%22N+70%C2%B057'37.9%22W/@45.1390904,-70.9681174,2774m)

Comment: "T" is the latitude band, between 40N and 48N.